# Postgres: is it possible to lock some rows for changing?

Tags: postgresql

I have pretty old tables, which hold records for clients' payments and commissions for several years. In regular business cycle sometimes it's needed to recalc commissions and update table. But usually period of recalulation 1 or 2 months backwards, not more.

Recently, in result of bug in php script, our developer recalculated commissions since the very beggining 0_0. And the process of recalculation is really complicated so it cant be restored just grabbing yeasterday's backup - data changes in noumerous databases, so restoring data is really complicated and awfully expensive procedure. And complains from clients and change in accounting...you know..Horor.

We can't split tables by periods. (Well we can, but it will take year to remake all data selects).

What I'm trying to think about is to set up some update trigger that would check date of the changing record and `allowed` date that should be less then the updating date. So in case of mistake or bug, when someone would try to update such 'restricted' row it would get an exception and keep the data unchaged.

Is that a good approach? How's that can be done - I mean trigger?

Comment: Is this MS SQL Server or PostgeSQL?  You should probably include the version as well since that may be relevant for people trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For postgres you can use a `check` constraint to ensure the allowed_date is always less than the update_date:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT datecheck CHECK (allowed_date < update_date);
```

Comment: beautifull!
is it possible to keep allowed date in separate table say - for different clients and branches?

Comment: As I see `check` cannot use selected variables, so either I should have one `allowed` date for all clients as constant in constraint (which is still better then nothing) or I will have to setup several default columns with `allowed` date. Still I could be perfest if it'd be possible to select in `check`

Comment: @DenisMatafonov unfortunately it's not possible to check the value of another row - only the row being updated/inserted